# set gridview column width in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i want to fix a grdview column width in page load event.

i bounded this gridview from c# and also uses a datasource from c#

i want to set width for "Address" column ,because it has long data.i also want to use auto scroll to this gridview .

here is my code...

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select DISTINCT FName+ ' ' +MName+ ' ' +LName as Name,"
             + " HomePhone,MobileNo1,"
             + " UPPER(ResAddr1) ++'  '+ UPPER(Resaddr2) ++'  '+ UPPER(ResAddr3) ++'  '+ UPPER(Resaddr4) ++'  '+ UPPER(Resaddr5) ++'  '+ UPPER(Resaddr6) ++'  '+ Pincode ++'  '+City as Address,"
             + " g.Category,f.GroupName as 'Group',Seats,"
             + " dbo.CONCATWTOTSHOW(d.MemberId,d.GID,d.CID)As SeatNo,"
             + " AmountExpected,AmountReceived,Discount,AmountPending,b.Remarks as Reference, (d.MemberId)"
             + " from Person_Master a INNER JOIN Member_Master b ON a.PersonId=b.PersonId"
             + " LEFT JOIN Payment_Master c ON b.MemberId = c.MemberId"
             + " INNER JOIN SeatAssign_Master d ON b.MemberId = d.MemberId"
             + " INNER JOIN Year_Master e ON b.Year = e.Id"
             + " INNER JOIN Group_Master f ON d.Gid=f.Gid"
             + " INNER JOIN Category_Master g ON d.Cid=g.Cid "
             + " where b.Year=2 and g.Cid=2 and b.Active=1 and d.Active=1 ", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so do it in RowCreated event

```
 GridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowCreated);

      void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 200;
           // GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderStyle.Width = 100;
        }
```

Comment: its not working because query is executed in page load event..and then data are bounded

Comment: in page load.. after databind. where to put it ??

Comment: i refined the answer check it again

Comment: Yes Your Code is Working Fine when i use div style="width:auto" for griview . i want to use div style ="width:1000px" ..... in this condition its not working

Comment: so if my answer in correct please accept it,for div style i think it should have enough with more than you sum of grid columns withs

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a Grid view **RowCreated** event and in that event write

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Width = Unit.Pixel(300);
```

Where  [1] is the column index.